# I'm searching for the meaning of "Up to"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

If we substitute this infinitesimal matrix A into orthogonality condition A^{t}A = 1 defined in chapter 1, we will get (1 + x A')^{t}(1 + A'J) =
(1 + x J^{t})(1 + x J) = 1, which is same as x J^{t} = -x J **UP TO** first order of x.

Comment: This is a mathematics question, not an English question.

Comment: No! I wish to know the meaning of 'up to' in this context!!!

Comment: "Up to" is in the jargon used in mathematics with a special meaning that is not found in general English dictionaries.

Comment: It is a technical term in mathematics, and will not be understood by the vast majority of native English speakers. I _think_ it means "ignoring all higher orders of x", but I don't know that what that means, unless it is another way of saying "ignoring all higher powers of x".

Comment: The description by @ColinFine is correct.  It means to ignore terms of x^2, x^3, and other higher orders of x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that in the sum of terms on the right side of the equation, one is ignoring all powers of x higher than 1. In general, these higher powers may or may not be integers. Ignoring these higher powers becomes a better and better approximation to the left-hand side of the equation the smaller x becomes. To define it precisely, you need to use mathematical limits. @ColinFine is correct. You won't find this in general English dictionaries.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this must understand the issue better than I do. :-) All I did was answer the question.

Comment: Someone downvoted my question too. I can't understand why someone made this.

Comment: @VanyushaPavlova I wonder the same thing sometimes myself. :-) In your case, the downvote may have been the result of a user feeling that your question was not a question of English language and usage but of mathematics.

Comment: I voted up for you. Can you vote up for me?

Comment: @VanyushaPavlova I thought I already had, because I didn't think you deserved a downvote for asking a well-defined question.